# Dealing with 2 items in a row when you have 3 columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In a 3 column grid if the last line has only 2 items is it possible to have them laid out like the attached image? Is this possible using just CSS and not adding a blank entry?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;

  
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;

  
}


}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Lines</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item7">8</div>
</div>

<p>You can refer to line numbers when placing grid items.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an [explicit `grid`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids) you can allow a specific child to span all columns by using `grid-column: -2 / -1;` on your last child. This tells the grid area to span from the third column line to the last column line, effectively getting space-between on the last row.

See below:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.grid-container>div:last-child {
  grid-column: -2 / -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Lines</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item7">8</div>
</div>

<p>You can refer to line numbers when placing grid items.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a repeating pattern of 3 elements (`3n`)

You want the last element `:last-child`  to be in the third column if it stands in the second `div:nth-child(3n - 1)`.

the rules together  would be `div:nth-child(3n - 1):last-child`.

Demo below

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* if last div is standing in the second column out of three, move it to third */
.grid-container>div:nth-child(3n - 1):last-child {
  grid-column: 3
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Lines</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item7">8</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item7">8</div>
  <div class="item7">9</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
</div>
```